# Theorem numbers in bold

Tags: numbering, theorems, bold

With the standard theorem-like environemnts (at least when using amsthm), one obtains something like

> Theorem 2.3.

where "Theorem" is in bold but "2.3." is not. I would like to have the number in bold too. A first solution may look like

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\textbf{\arabic{section}.\arabic{thm}}}
```

The problem with this solution is that every reference to a theorem number will be in bold as well, and I don't want this inside the text.

Is there a way to have only the numbers in theorem headings in bold?

**EDIT** As it was pointed out, my actual example is slightly more complicated than that. I am using a modified theorem style; a minimal example follows

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm, lipsum}
\swapnumbers

\newtheoremstyle{dotless-thm}
{3pt}
{3pt}
{\it}
{}
{\bfseries}
{}
{.5em}
{}

\theoremstyle{dotless-thm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Even though I use `bfseries` for the theorem body font, the number appears in normal font.

Comment: Can you please post a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) that illustrates this behaviour? The standard `plain` style of `amsthm` typesets both the name and the number boldfaced.

Comment: I think editing `\thethm` is probably not the way to achieve what you want. amsthm and ntheorem packages provide their own functionality for changing how theorems appear...

Comment: The problem is with `\swapnumbers` commenting that out makes the number bold. So there's something funny going on with swap numbers and theorem head styling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the internal command `\swappedhead` of `amsart.cls` which changes the number font when the `\swapnumbers` command is invoked. This can be done adding the lines between `\makeatletter` and \makeatother in my example code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers

\makeatletter
\def\swappedhead#1#2#3{%
  % original definition:
  % \thmnumber{\@upn{\the\thm@headfont#2\@ifnotempty{#1}{.~}}}%
  % change:
  \thmnumber{\@upn{\the\thm@headfont#2\@ifnotempty{#1}{.~}}}%
  \thmname{#1}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{dotless-thm}
  {3pt}
  {3pt}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {.5em}
  {}
\theoremstyle{dotless-thm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
Test
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: as Seamus has suggested in his answer, the fact that the number font for theorem-like structures changes if the `\swapnumbers` switch is in use is a feature provided by the AMS document classes.

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't a bug or error: it's part of AMS style that if the number is swapped, its font attributes matches the section heading...

Comment: @Seamus: Yes, I know that... and no one has suggested it was a bug. I'll, however, add a anote to my solution.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [amsthdoc.pdf](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf)

> In AMS document classes, when numbers are swapped, the style of the numbers
>   matches that of section headings; this may not be the same style as the rest of the
>   theorem heading.

That's what's causing the problem. If you get rid of `\swapnumbers` then you should be fine. Or if you really want swapnumbers, you might need to do some jiggery pokery with the section fonts or some such...

The [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package is more powerful, and might provide a simpler way to achieve what you want. Very quickly, you could do this.

```
%\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem, lipsum}
\theoremstyle{change}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Note the change of documentclass: there seems to be a conflict between `amsart` and `ntheorem`.

Comment: Annoyingly, `amsart` also seems to conflict with `titlesec` so my preferred way of hacking your section headings into bold so that they fit with the theorem style doesn't work...

Comment: re conflict between `amsart` and `ntheorem`, that is to be expected. `amsart` doesn't *load* `amsthm`, those features are built in directly; that is true for all ams document classes. in fact, the `amsthm` package is slightly different (e.g. in choice of heading fonts) from what's in the document classes. as someone has already said, what's in the document classes is tailored for ams style. if something different is wanted, creating a derivative class (or using a different one entirely) is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Use the asmthm style file and then

```
\newtheoremstyle{common}
    {6pt plus 5\p@ minus 2\p@}% above space (default)
    {6pt plus 5\p@ minus 2\p@}% below space
    {\itshape}% body font
    {0em}% indent
    {\bfseries}% head font
    {}% punct after head
    {.5em}% space
    {}% custom
\theoremstyle{common}

%%%With Chapter Number
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]%
```

Comment: Thorsten edited your post and I approved it. You can mark code by indenting four spaces, or by selecting the code and clicking the `10101` button.

Comment: I edited my question. I am actually doing something like that but the number appears in normal font instead of bold.